# jQuery Mobile .trigger('pagecreate') vs .trigger('create')

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile `.trigger('pagecreate')` vs `.trigger('create')`

**What's the difference?** When I'm reloading the entire `data-role="page"`

`.trigger('pagecreate')` works but `.trigger('create')` doesn't. Any reason why?

Comment: as you can see both are very different events!!!

Comment: `pagecreate` is used when dynamic elements are added to / or changes made to `data-role=` `header`, `footer`, `panel`. `create` is used for the rest of widgets, dynamically inserted.