# Uncaught error : cannot read property "options " of undefined .j-query mobile : 1.3.2 5454 on page.trigger("page-create")

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap/android code like

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" data-position=fixed class="ui-header"> 
                <img src="soso.png" class="menu">
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="inbox">
            <div data-role="header" data-position=fixed class="ui-header"> 
                <img src="soso.png" class="menu">
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="panel" class="nav-panel">
            <div id="sidemenuwrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#inbox"></a></li>
                </ul>
                         </div>
                </div>
```

in my main html page .
i want to add a sidebar to this application so i am adding the html to this page like

```
 var panel = "<div data-role="panel" class="nav-panel">"+$('nav-panel').html+'</div>
   page.find('[data-role=content]').after(panel);
   page.trigger("page-create");
```

on pressing the image in the header , the nav-panel will open if it is closed , will close if it is opened. i am getting this error on the last line of code when i fo from home to inbox and back to home via sidepanel the sidepanel is getting blocked that is nothing is happening on clicking the header icon , every thing is good in the event handler function of it

Comment: Is it `.trigger("page-create");` or `.trigger("pagecreate");` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350110/jquery-mobile-triggerpagecreate-vs-triggercreate

Comment: .trigger("pagecreate") i am sorry for the typo in the question